# In this simple multithreading example, why does the last method in Main() always execute last?

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
static int i = 0;

static void Main()
{
    ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();
    new Thread(tt.Incr).Start();
    tt.I();
    tt.I2();
}

void Incr()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        i++;
    }
}

void I()
{
    while(i <= 3)
    {
        if(i==3)
            break;
        Console.WriteLine("Value of i in I:{0}",i);
    }
}

void I2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t\tFinally i is:{0}\n\n",i);
}
```

I have run this piece of code about a few hundred times now  and find that I2 always executes last. Why does this happen? May be a few hundred times is not enough to see the true unpredictability of threads?

[Output of 11 runs](http://pastebin.com/qmQ7f2zL)

Comment: I see more than one downvote on each answer. Please drop a comment on why an answer is downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `I2()` *is* the last method in `Main()` and it is not threaded in any way.

So what's the question, why the thread finishes earlier?

That's because `I2()` is run *after* `I()` and the while-loop in `I()` effectively waits for the thread to finish first.

Comment: Should clarify "effectively waits" .. because there is no synchronization.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What is to prevent `Incr` from finishing after `I2`? answer: nothing

Comment: @Servy: `I()` is preventing just that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman well if the timeslice of the last iteration of `Incr` ends just after i++ it would allow `I` and `I2` to execute (and likely finish) before going back to `Incr`, so they could still finish executing in any order they want.

Comment: @Servy this would not affect the output. Think about it for a while. The Console.WriteLine is after the increment. The effect you describe cannot be detected from the output of the program. Thus it may actually happened!

Comment: But the thread would not produce any output after that so it would be undetectable and academic.

Comment: @pst: it waits for the shared (non volatile) `i` to become `3`... how clear do you want it?

Answer (score 0):

The method `I2` will always be executed last. This has nothing to do with threads.

```
static void Main()
{
    ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();
    new Thread(tt.Incr).Start();
    tt.I(); // This will be executed first
    tt.I2(); // This will be executed last
}
```

The flow of the newly started thread and the current thread is not synchronized, but the current thread will continiue its operation in a synchronous fashion executing statements in the order as the appear. In this case `I()` will be called before `I2()`.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't explain why the thread's output is before that of I2's - there is *no guarantee*.

Comment: @pst yeah, but the question is about _why_ I2() executes lasts.